# Add a UITableView to a view controller swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I don't understand what am I doing wrong,
I am trying to make an add button on the navigation bar so when you click it a little table view will be open in the page bottom and the user would be able to choose what to add (photo, video, and so on..)
I connected the tableView with my cocoa touch class, as you can see it here:

```
class addTable: UITableView {

    let addObjects = ["Add Photo","Add Video","Add Link", "Add Sound Record", "Add Sound Track"]

    override func cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addItem", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel.text = addObjects[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func numberOfRowsInSection(section: Int) -> Int {
        return addObjects.count
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

I really don't understand why doesn't it work, the number of rows in the table is not even equals to the `addObjects.count`

I really hope you understand my question, Thank you guys!!

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want use a UIViewController with a UItableView inside or a UITableViewController?

Answer (score 2):

You have subclassed `UITableView`, but this is probably not necessary.

What you want is for this class to be the dataSource for a standard table view.

```
class addTable : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource{

    func cellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView:UITableView!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addItem", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = addObjects[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addObjects.count
    }


    func  numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

Then, in your view controller you can set an instance of this class as your tableview's data source -

```
self.myTableView.dataSource=addTable();
```

How you allocate and initialise the actual tableview is up to you - storyboard or through code, but it can just be a straight tableview.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer,
I tried to do what you told me to,
but first the UITableViewDataSource is not a class as you wrote, but a protocol,
and a protocol is just like an interface from what I understand,
so accordingly, I can’t add fields like the addObjects array in my code above, and I can’t implement methods there, so how is it done, I’d love it if you could give an example or more detail about it, Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer and also corrected the function prototypes

Comment: Hi, thank you again, now I'm getting a compiler error says: type 'addTable' does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource, although the required methods are implemented , why is that?

Comment: you know what I overcome that problem but there is a runtime error now : tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Any chance you could update with the solution on this @LiranRevivo ?

Comment: Hi, Generally what you should do is add the UITableView as a subView to the UIViewController view, and let it be a field in the UIViewController class, (implementing a sub class of UITable view is mostly not necessary). after you added it as a field and subView, define the UIViewController as UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, implement the required methods cellForRowAtIndexPath and numbersOfRowsInSection. Finally, in the viewDidLoad method (or in the initialiser, doesn't matter) perform: myTableView.delegate = self, myTableView.dataSource = self.. this should work! GL! @denislexic

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it. Will give it a go!